# The question is related to Assembly x86-32 RET n instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, return, masm32

I know the meaning of Ret n but I can't figure out its role to maintaining program's runtime stack? I'm kind of confuse there. Do ret have somethig to do with stack?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  See [here](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html).  You are only interested in the pseudo-code for “near return.”

Comment: yes , I was able to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ret n` is like `ret` + `add esp, n`.  You use it for caller-pops calling conventions.

**Plain `ret` is like `pop eip`**.  (`pop eip` isn't a valid instruction, but it nicely expresses what `ret` does).  Yes it uses the stack; read the documentation.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html (specifically the "near return" part.)

"far ret" is more complicated, but not used in 32 or 64-bit code with a flat memory model.  i.e. not used at all in normal code.